# How can I know the protocol versions supported at OpenSSL1.1.0g

Tags: tls, openssl, tls-intercept, tls-downgrade

How can I identify the versions (TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.0, SSLv3, etc.) supported in OpenSSL1.1.0g when I manually compile it from its source (NOT the one shipped with the OS like ubuntu) without explicit disabling any version in the compilation?

Q: Is SSLv3 supported by default in OpenSSL1.1.0g? How can I know this?

Comment: you mean like `openssl ciphers -s`? https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/apps/ciphers.html

Comment: No I mean versions (TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.0, SSLv3, etc.) not ciphers.

Comment: check out my link above

Comment: @schroeder: the list of ciphersuites supported does NOT tell you the protocol versions supported. Steffen's answer is correct. Also crossdupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27430158/list-supported-ssl-tls-versions-for-a-specific-openssl-build

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 so the list of protocol versions in the link, what's that?

Comment: @schroeder the ciphersuites versions is different than the negotiated versions. So a client can support SSLv3 ciphersuites (AES128_SHA) but not negotiate the protocol version SSLv3 as a protocol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The test program `openssl s_server` has several option to choose the SSL/TLS version, i.e. `-ssl2`, `-ssl3`, `-tls1`, `-tls1_1`, .... Starting with OpenSSL 1.1.0 the usage `openssl s_server -help` shows all actually supported options, i.e. `-ssl3` is only shown if SSLv3 is actually supported. 
With earlier versions of OpenSSL the usage might show version which were not actually supported but an attempt to actually use these resulted in an error.

> Q: Is SSLv3 supported by default in OpenSSL1.1.0g? How can I know this?

Since you compile it from source you can just look at the output from `config`:

```
$ ./config
...
Configuring OpenSSL version 1.1.0g-dev (0x10100070L)
...
    no-ssl3         [default]  OPENSSL_NO_SSL3
```

Thus, it looks like SSLv3 is disabled by default.

Comment: I did `openssl s_server -help` and I get option: `-no_ssl3`. Does this meand ssl3 is supported? In the same time, there is no option to just talk ssl3, while there are options to just talk tls1, tls1_1, etc. Is there any reliable way through whcih I know which versions are supported by default? Unfortunately it is difficult to know as ssl3 not supported by many servers to test connecting to them, and TLS does send the max. version so its hard to tell the min.

Comment: @user9371654: The `-no_ssl3` etc options are not relevant for this. If you don't have a `-ssl3` option then you don't have support for SSLv3.

Comment: If I have it already installed in my system, can I run the ./config to check that I am having it disabled without affecting anything?

Comment: it is working with me & I do not want to recompile or reconfigure it. I have made custom configurations before., Will ./config restore the default? Not sure the ./config will perform anything that changes my current installation? sorry but I'm not a linux user.

Comment: @user9371654: I'm not sure what your problem is. You asked if SSLv3 is supported by default and I've shown you the output of `./config` which clearly says it is disabled by default. There is no need to run `./config` yourself unless you want to see how this behaves with a different version of OpenSSL. If you just want to know if SSLv3 is supported by your current installation see if `openssl s_server` supports the `-ssl3` option.

Comment: If I run the command ./configure will this override any previous configurations I have made before I compile OpenSSL? I need to know because I executed ./config as you posted. If this is the case (i.e. it will override previous configurations), then I need to recompile the library, right? because as I said I made custom configurations before I install it previously.

Comment: @user9371654: running `config` prepares everything for compiling. It does not change anything on the existing build but only affects newly compiled builds.

Comment: For completeness, below 1.1.0 there isn't an actual `-help` option, but any invalid option gives the usage message -- including `-help` or `-zowie` or `-????????`